# Limit access and editing menu by user

Tags: routes

I have created a new menu and I'm trying to limit the access to a particular user to edit instead of role with the following code but it's not working, I still can't see the menu and edit the menus items by logging in with the relevant user login (user id 3 in this case). Wondering what's the proper way of doing.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */

function menu_access_by_uid_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/new-menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'New Menu',  
    'access callback' => 'menu_access_by_uid_validate',       
  ); 

  return $items;
}


function menu_access_by_uid_validate() {

 global $user;

 if (user_is_logged_in() && ($user->uid == 1 || $user->uid == 3)){
   return TRUE;
 }

 return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: If this is a custom page then where is the page callback? If it is a pre-defined page then hook_menu_alter should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice module to handle visibility of menu items. You can use the module or see code in side the module.

May be It will help you. I am not sure :P

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility

Comment: This is indeed a nice module but I'm afraid it only limit the access to the menu's item, not the menu itself a s a whole and besides, it also limit by Role whereas I need to limit by individual user. Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is limit access to the admin pages for a specific menu then something like this should work:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-new-menu']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_by_uid';
  $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-new-menu/%']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_by_uid';
}

function mymodule_access_by_uid() {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid == 1 || $user->uid == 3) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

You need to use [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to add your own access callback for an **existing** page because [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is for defining your own menu items and page callbacks.

Also, I don't think you need [user_is_logged_in()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) since that's already implied if the uid is something other than 0.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have tested your code but it seems not working fully. Every time I access the page "admin/structure/menu/manage/new-menu"  or ".../menu-apple/add" or ".../menu-apple/edit", I see only the same interface like in "admin/structure/menu". Any further to fine tune ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a slight mistake when I edited my example code to use your menu name. The path should have had "menu-new-menu" rather than just "new-menu". I think that should fix it. Also, make sure to clear your cache when you change the code.